# Can we disable Full text in SQL without installing any application

Tags: sql-server, testing

I want to run an application in both the ways : disabling full text feature and then enabling full text. I want to disable/enable this before running the application. How can this be done? I am using sql server 2017.

Can you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG (Transact-SQL)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)
```